# Laravel consulta que antes tardaba mili-segundos ahora tarda segundos y el numero de registros es el mismo

Tags: php, laravel

Bueno antes tenia esta consulta en una aplicación de Laravel y se ejecutaba en muy pocos mili-segundos, pero ahora esta misma consulta tarda en ejecutarse 40 segundos. El numero de registros en mi aplicación es el mismo. No se cual puede ser el motivo de que ahora tarde tanto tiempo en ejecutarse.

```
            $products = DB::Table('product_details')->whereActive(1)->whereFeatured(1)
            ->join('product_stock', 'product_stock.product_id', '=', 'product_details.product_id')
            ->join('products', 'product_details.product_id', '=', 'products.code')
            ->join('categories', 'categories.code', '=', 'products.category_id')
            ->join('manufacturers','manufacturers.code','=','products.manufacturer_id')
            ->take(4)
            ->get(['products.name', 'products.code', 'products.slug', 'products.id', 'product_stock.stock','product_details.img','product_stock.fecha','manufacturers.code','categories.code']);
```

Comment: Yo comprobaría el que las tablas a la que accedes tengan establecido un índice. El acceder a una tabla sin índice incrementa el tiempo de la consulta bastante, sobre todo si se trata de una tabla con una buena cantidad de registros.

Comment: ¿Esta misma consulta en SQL puro desde tu motor de bases de datos tarda lo mismo?